# postgresql query result using where condition another query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-12

my goal is detect all usernames and count each username login time in 24 hours.
I was rite code separately but i cant combine it.

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT "username"
FROM
   my_table;
```

my second query is get me count log related this username

```
select count(*) 
from my_table as "foo" where "username" = 'example_username' and  "foo"."timestamp" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS' AND NOW()
```

ı want to write one query this query detect unique/distinct usernames and return me last 24 hours logs for each username

if we think this query return a variable list

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT "username"           
FROM
   my_table;
```

variable_list =(username1,username2,...)

run that query for each username in variable_list

```
select count(*) 
from my_table as "foo" where "username" = 'example_username' and  "foo"."timestamp" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS' AND NOW()
```

how can ı do that ? and what is the right way for solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CTE to make a list of users and then just use a left join with aggregation.

```
WITH user_list as (SELECT
   DISTINCT "username"
   FROM
   my_table)
SELECT 
  user_list."username"
  ,count(*) 
FROM user_list 
LEFT JOIN my_table as "foo" 
   ON "foo"."username"=user_list."username"
WHERE  "foo"."timestamp" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS' AND NOW()
GROUP BY user_list."username"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a `WHERE` clause.  Assuming that you have no future timestamps:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username         
FROM my_table
WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS' ;
```

If you want to count users in the last 24 hours, use aggregation:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS')     
FROM my_table
GROUP BY username;
```

Comment: This will not display all usernames, just the ones that logged on in the last 24h. So you will have no 0 counts.